# how to remove or unset cookie in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have gone through the documentation here [cookie laravel 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies)

But I am unable to check how to **remove** or **unset** cookie in `laravel 4.2` ?

even in `laravel 4.0` there was a `Cookie::forget('cookieKey');` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still neet to send the cookie with your response like this

```
$cookie = Cookie::forget('cookieKey');
return Redirect::to('page')->withCookie($cookie);
```

Comment: but they haven't written in their documentation and also in my case there is no redirect